# How to read a file in binary numbers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file .* docx and translate it to bits and bytes.

But it outputs my docx file in this form:
docx
<class 'bytes'>
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\xdf\xa4\xd2lZ\x01'

How do I change this piece of code so that I see the output data in bits and bytes ('0' and '1')

code:

```
    def on_clicked_IS(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open File', './'  # , 'Files (*.html *.txt *.log)'
)
        if fname:
            print()
            if fname.endswith("docx") :
                print("docx")
                with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.read()
                    print(type(self.data))
                    print(self.data[:20])
```

Comment: What exactly *is* your expected output?

Comment: so that I can see the output data in bits and bytes ('0' and '1')